# How do I send cookies in flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql

I am working on an Flutter App which needs to send cookies to the api to return data. I tried to find solutions online on how to send a cookie with every graphql request that I make but none of them works.

This is my code snippet for the graphql client

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final HttpLink link = HttpLink(
    'https://myApp.de/graphql/',
  );

  ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
    GraphQLClient(
      cache: GraphQLCache(),
      link: link,
    ),
  );
```